# Add top row value to current row based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

my current tabular output is

```
        ---------------------------------------------------
        |    id               col1            col2        |
        ---------------------------------------------------
        |    1           |    test1      |    1           |
        |    2           |    test11     |    0           |
        |    3           |    test12     |    0           |
        |    4           |    test13     |    0           |
        |    5           |    test14     |    0           |
        |    6           |    test2      |    2           |
        |    7           |    test21     |    0           |
        |    8           |    test22     |    0           |
        |    9           |    test23     |    0           |
        |    10          |    test24     |    0           |
        ---------------------------------------------------
```

Expected output is

```
        ---------------------------------------------------
        |    id               col1            col2        |
        ---------------------------------------------------
        |    1           |    test1      |    1           |
        |    2           |    test11     |    1           |
        |    3           |    test12     |    1           |
        |    4           |    test13     |    1           |
        |    5           |    test14     |    1           |
        |    6           |    test2      |    2           |
        |    7           |    test21     |    2           |
        |    8           |    test22     |    2           |
        |    9           |    test23     |    2           |
        |    10          |    test24     |    2           |
        ---------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible without cursor? Is there a way that I can add top row value to current row value on a condition when current row value is 0?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  There are better answers for later versions.

Comment: SQL server 2008. Let me know if 2012 has a better way to handle this. I can move to 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find the last non-zero value of `col2` like:

```
select  id
,       col1
,       (
        select  top 1 col2
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.id <= yt1.id
                and yt2.col2 <> 0
        order by
                yt2.id desc
        )
from    YourTable yt1
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6faca/3/0)

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot. This works in 2012 but not in 2008. Let me know if I have an option in 2008. If not, i will move to 2012.

Comment: After re-reading your post I think you're not looking for a running sum, but just for the last non-zero value.  The updated answer should work in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I don't think the answer I was about to add will add anything more than this answer already has, but in the interest of being a helpful member of the community here is my take on the criteria: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/deaea/1

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're after a running sum.  This should work in 2005 or later:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
    (
        id INT PRIMARY KEY
        , col1 VARCHAR(20)
        , col2 INT
    );
INSERT @tmp
VALUES
(1, 'test1',  1)
, (2, 'test11', 0)
, (3, 'test12', 0)
, (4, 'test13', 0)
, (5, 'test14', 0)
, (6, 'test2', 2)
, (7, 'test21', 0)
, (8, 'test22', 0)
, (9, 'test23', 0)
, (10, 'test24', 0);


SELECT 
    t1.id
    , t1.col1
    , CASE t1.col2
        WHEN 0 
            THEN t2.col2
        ELSE 
            t1.col2
    END col2
FROM 
    @tmp t1
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT 
            TOP 1 col2
        FROM 
            @tmp t3
        WHERE 
            t3.id <= t1.id
            AND 
            t3.col2 > 0
        ORDER BY 
            t3.id DESC
    ) t2
```